# issue when use typeahead package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-typeahead

I trying to build a suggestion when I search some name of a country, so I use Type Ahead but it not working.
Ncov19 class have properties is String Country
When I implement it on TypeAheadField it is return null but I use TextField to work with getCountrySuggestion

```
import 'package:covid19_app/bloc/ncov19_bloc.dart';
import 'package:covid19_app/bloc/ncov19_event.dart';
import 'package:covid19_app/bloc/ncov19_state.dart';
import 'package:covid19_app/models/ncov_19.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_typeahead/flutter_typeahead.dart';

class Ncov19Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Ncov19ScreenState createState() => _Ncov19ScreenState();
}

class _Ncov19ScreenState extends State<Ncov19Screen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    BlocProvider.of<Ncov19Bloc>(context).add(Ncov19RequestAll());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: TypeAheadField<Ncov19>(
                  suggestionsCallback: (value) async {
                    return await BlocProvider.of<Ncov19Bloc>(context)
                        .ncov19repository
                        .ncov19apiClient
                        .getCountrySuggestions(value);
                  },
                )),
            Container(
              width: size.size.width * 0.95,
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Đất nước', icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
                onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                  BlocProvider.of<Ncov19Bloc>(context)
                      .add(Ncov19RequestByCountry(country: value));
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: BlocBuilder<Ncov19Bloc, Ncov19State>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is Ncov19Initial) {
                    return Center(child: Text('Chọn đất nước'));
                  }
                  if (state is Ncov19LoadInProgress) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                  if (state is Ncov19LoadSuccessCountry) {
                    final ncov19 = state.ncov19;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: ncov19.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, int) =>
                          Text('${ncov19[int].country}'),
                    );
                  }
                  if (state is Ncov19LoadSuccessAllCountry) {
                    final ncov19All = state.ncov19All;
                    return ListView(
                      children: [
                        Center(
                          child: Text('${ncov19All.confirmed}'),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                  if (state is Ncov19LoadFailure) {
                    return Text(
                      state.error,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a Bloc:
State:

```
`

import 'package:covid19_app/models/ncov19_all.dart';
    import 'package:covid19_app/models/ncov_19.dart';
    import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    
    abstract class Ncov19State extends Equatable {
      const Ncov19State();
      @override
      List<Object> get props => [];
    }
    
    class Ncov19Initial extends Ncov19State {}
    
    class Ncov19LoadInProgress extends Ncov19State {}
    
    class Ncov19LoadSuccessCountry extends Ncov19State {
      final List<Ncov19> ncov19;
    
      Ncov19LoadSuccessCountry({@required this.ncov19});
      @override
      List<Object> get props => [];
    }
    
    class Ncov19LoadSuccessAllCountry extends Ncov19State {
      final Ncov19All ncov19All;
    
      Ncov19LoadSuccessAllCountry({@required this.ncov19All});
      @override
      List<Object> get props => [];
    }
    
    class Ncov19LoadFailure extends Ncov19State {
      final String error;
    
      Ncov19LoadFailure(this.error);
    }
    `
```

Event:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    
    abstract class Ncov19Event extends Equatable {
      const Ncov19Event();
    }
    
    class Ncov19RequestByCountry extends Ncov19Event {
      final String country;
      const Ncov19RequestByCountry({@required this.country});
      @override
      List<Object> get props => [];
    }
    
    class Ncov19RequestAll extends Ncov19Event {
      const Ncov19RequestAll();
      @override
      List<Object> get props => [];
    }
```

Bloc:

```
`import 'dart:async';
    
    import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
    import 'package:covid19_app/models/ncov19_all.dart';
    import 'package:covid19_app/models/ncov_19.dart';
    import 'package:covid19_app/repositories/ncov19_repository.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'ncov19_event.dart';
    import 'ncov19_state.dart';
    
    class Ncov19Bloc extends Bloc<Ncov19Event, Ncov19State> {
      final Ncov19Repository ncov19repository;
      Ncov19Bloc({@required this.ncov19repository}) : super(Ncov19Initial());
    
      @override
      Stream<Ncov19State> mapEventToState(
        Ncov19Event event,
      ) async* {
        if (event is Ncov19RequestByCountry) {
          yield Ncov19LoadInProgress();
    
          try {
            final List<Ncov19> ncov19 =
                await ncov19repository.getCountrySuggestions(event.country);
            yield Ncov19LoadSuccessCountry(ncov19: ncov19);
          } catch (error) {
            yield Ncov19LoadFailure(error.toString());
          }
        }
        if (event is Ncov19RequestAll) {
          yield Ncov19LoadInProgress();
          try {
            final Ncov19All ncov19All = await ncov19repository.getNcov19ByAll();
            yield Ncov19LoadSuccessAllCountry(ncov19All: ncov19All);
          } catch (error) {
            yield Ncov19LoadFailure(error.toString());
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `
```

Ncov19_api_client:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:covid19_app/models/ncov19_all.dart';
import 'package:covid19_app/models/ncov_19.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../models/ncov_19.dart';

class Ncov19ApiClient {
  static const baseUrl = 'https://covid-api.mmediagroup.fr/v1/cases';
  final http.Client httpClient;

  Ncov19ApiClient({@required this.httpClient});
  // Future<Ncov19> fetNcov19ByCountry(String country) async {
  //   final ncov19Url = '$baseUrl?country=$country';
  //   final ncov19Response = await this.httpClient.get(Uri.parse(ncov19Url));

  //   if (ncov19Response.statusCode != 200) {
  //     throw Exception('Lỗi truy cập');
  //   }
  //   final ncov19Json = jsonDecode(ncov19Response.body);
  //   return Ncov19.fromJson(ncov19Json);
  // }

  Future<List<Ncov19>> getCountrySuggestions(String query) async {
    final url = Uri.parse('https://covid-api.mmediagroup.fr/v1/cases');
    final responseCountry = await this.httpClient.get(url);
    if (responseCountry.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Lỗi truy cập');
    }
    final Map<String, dynamic> nCov19AllCountry =
        json.decode(responseCountry.body);

    return nCov19AllCountry.entries
        .map((json) => Ncov19(country: json.key))
        .where((nCov) {
      final queryUpperFisrt =
          '${query[0].toUpperCase()}${query.substring(1).toLowerCase()}';
      final countryUpperFisrt =
          '${nCov.country[0].toUpperCase()}${nCov.country.substring(1).toLowerCase()}';
      return countryUpperFisrt.contains(queryUpperFisrt);
    }).toList();
  }

  Future<Ncov19All> fetNcov19All() async {
    final ncov19Url = '$baseUrl';
    final ncov19Response = await this.httpClient.get(Uri.parse(ncov19Url));

    if (ncov19Response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Lỗi truy cập');
    }
    final ncov19AllJson = jsonDecode(ncov19Response.body);
    return Ncov19All.fromJson(ncov19AllJson);
  }
}
```

repositories:

```
import 'package:covid19_app/models/ncov19_all.dart';
import 'package:covid19_app/models/ncov_19.dart';
import 'package:covid19_app/repositories/ncov19_api_client.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Ncov19Repository {
  final Ncov19ApiClient ncov19apiClient;

  Ncov19Repository({@required this.ncov19apiClient});
  // Future<Ncov19> getNcov19ByCountry(String country) async {
  //   return ncov19apiClient.fetNcov19ByCountry(country);
  // }
  Future<List<Ncov19>> getCountrySuggestions(String query) async {
    return ncov19apiClient.getCountrySuggestions(query);
  }

  Future<Ncov19All> getNcov19ByAll() async {
    return ncov19apiClient.fetNcov19All();
  }
}
```

Main:

```
import 'package:covid19_app/bloc/ncov19_bloc.dart';
import 'package:covid19_app/repositories/ncov19_api_client.dart';
import 'package:covid19_app/repositories/ncov19_repository.dart';
import 'package:covid19_app/screens/ncov19_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  final Ncov19Repository ncov19repository = Ncov19Repository(
      ncov19apiClient: Ncov19ApiClient(
    httpClient: http.Client(),
  ));
  runApp(MyApp(ncov19repository: ncov19repository));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Ncov19Repository ncov19repository;

  const MyApp({Key key, @required this.ncov19repository}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<Ncov19Bloc>(
      create: (context) => Ncov19Bloc(ncov19repository: ncov19repository),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Ncov19 tracker',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Ncov19Screen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Am I missing something or doing wrong?